# Coding in onStop crashes the app

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 public void onStop() {
        information=Option.getText().toString();
        if (!information.equals("")) {
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "All unsubmitted information will be discarded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_back_press,null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder.setView(v);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            TextView cancel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "Feedback not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            TextView send = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Send);
            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    FeedbackConcernsFragment.super.onStop();
                   // FeedbackConcernsFragment.onStop();
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "Feedback sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }else {
            super.onStop();
        }

    }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                Process: com.guideme, PID: 23746
>                                                                android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment
>   FeedbackConcernsFragment{22c43a48 #2 id=0x7f110159} did not call
>   through to super.onStop()
>                                                                    at android.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:1873)
>                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
>                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1167)
>                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:718)
>                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1496)
>                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:495)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2288)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:179)
>                                                                    at com.guideme.activities.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:352)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2266)
>                                                                    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2724)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2496)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397020/android-app-supernotcalledexception-activity-did-not-call-through-to-super-onst)

Answer (score 1):

The crashlog actually tells you the problem:

> android.util.SuperNotCalledException

The main lifecycle functions must always call their super function. So just add

```
super.onStop();
```

as the first line in the method and the code will work :)

PS: and don't forget to remove the super call in the else branch, since that is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should call super in onStop.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: If information is not empty I don't want to call super.on stop

Comment: @JarinRocks; The error is telling you that you must call super.onStop, you don't have a choice if you choose to override that method